# why does @transactional rolls back even when running on a new transaction?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am learning spring transaction propagation. so i have three inner services in Organization Service.

**OrganizationService**

```
@Service
public class OrganizationServiceImpl implements OrganizationService {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeService employeeService;

    @Autowired
    HealthIsuranceService healthInsuranceService;

    @Autowired
    InsuranceLogService insuranceLogService;

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void joinOrganization(Employee employee, EmployeeHealthInsurance employeeHealthInsurance) {
        employeeService.insertEmployee(employee);

        healthInsuranceService.registerEmployeeHealthInsurance(employeeHealthInsurance);

        InsuranceLog insuranceLog = new InsuranceLog();
        insuranceLog.setInformation("new log information");
        insuranceLogService.logIt(insuranceLog);

    }

    @Override
    public void leaveOrganization(Employee employee, EmployeeHealthInsurance employeeHealthInsurance) {
        employeeService.deleteEmployeeById(employee.getEmpId());
        healthInsuranceService.deleteEmployeeHealthInsuranceById(employeeHealthInsurance.getEmpId());

    }
}
```

**HealthInsuranceService**

```
@Service
public class HealthInsuranceServiceImpl implements HealthIsuranceService{

    @Autowired
    HealthInsuranceDao healthInsuranceDao;

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void registerEmployeeHealthInsurance(EmployeeHealthInsurance employeeHealthInsurance) {
        healthInsuranceDao.registerEmployeeHealthInsurance(employeeHealthInsurance);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteEmployeeHealthInsuranceById(String empid) {
        healthInsuranceDao.deleteEmployeeHealthInsuranceById(empid);
    }
}
```

**EmployeeService**

```
@Service
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeDao employeeDao;

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void insertEmployee(Employee employee) {
        employeeDao.insertEmployee(employee);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteEmployeeById(String empid) {
        employeeDao.deleteEmployeeById(empid);
    }
}
```

**EmployeeLogService**

```
@Service
public class InsuranceLogServiceImpl implements InsuranceLogService{

    @Autowired
    private InsuranceLogDao insuranceLogDao;

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void logIt(InsuranceLog logInfo){
            int i=0;

            int j =0;
            int result = i/j;
            insuranceLogDao.logIt(logInfo);
    }


}
```

here is my scenario :-

1. `insertEmployee(employee)` and `registerEmployeeHealthInsurance(employeeHealthInsurance)` should run in the same transaction so that either of them commits together or rolls back together. `logIt(insuranceLog)` is optional when these two transactions commits. failing to log should not roll back above transactions.
2. `logIt(insuranceLog)` should all also roll back when either of `insertEmployee(employee)` , `registerEmployeeHealthInsurance(employeeHealthInsurance)` fails to commit.

how can i achieve this ?

Comment: you could remove the `logIt` method from the `joinOrganization` method and create a wrapper method which first executes `joinOrganization`. As soon as `joinOrganization` sucessfully commits you run `logIt`. If `joinOrganization` fails, dont run `logIt`.

Comment: I think @pero_hero is right, it's better to simplify your transaction usage.